# Kubernetes - Error message ImagePullBackOff when deploy a pod

Tags: image, kubernetes

Hello kubernetes developers,

i get the error 'ImagePullBackOff' if deploy a pod in kubernetes. 
Pulling in docker to get the image from git-hub repository is no problem. But what is wrong with my configuration?

I tried this workaround to create a secret-key with the following command.

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry secretkey \
        --docker-server=registry.hub.docker.com \
        --docker-username=reponame \
        --docker-password=repopassword \
        --docker-email=repoemail
```

And this is the yaml file to create the kubernetes pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: gps-restful-server
  name: gps-restful-server
spec:
  containers:
  - image: tux/gps:latest
    name: gps-restful-server
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
    resources: {}
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/www/html/modules
      name: gps-modules
    - mountPath: /var/www/html/profiles
      name: gps-profile
    - mountPath: /var/www/html/themes
      name: gps-theme
    - mountPath: /var/www/html/sites
      name: gps-sites
    imagePullPolicy: Always
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: secretkey
  volumes:
  - name: gps-modules
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: gps-modules
  - name: gps-profile
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: gps-profile
  - name: gps-theme
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: gps-theme
  - name: gps-sites
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: gps-sites
status: {}
```

To deploy the pod in kubernetes, i execute the command:

```
kubectl create -f gps-restful-server-pod.yaml.
```

Get the status from the pod:

```
kubectl get all
NAME                           READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/telemetry-restful-server   0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          12m  
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP    1h
```

Description of the pod:

```
kubectl describe pod gps-restful-server
Name:               gps-restful-server
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               minikube/192.168.178.92
Start Time:         Thu, 14 Feb 2019 16:56:25 +0100
Labels:             io.kompose.service=gps-restful-server
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Pending
IP:                 172.17.0.3
Containers:
  gps-restful-server:
    Container ID:
    Image:          tux/gps:latest
    Image ID:
    Port:           8080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-4t28k (ro)
      /var/www/html/modules from gps-modules (rw)
      /var/www/html/profiles from gps-profile (rw)
      /var/www/html/sites from gps-sites (rw)
      /var/www/html/themes from gps-theme (rw)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  gps-modules:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  gps-modules
    ReadOnly:   false
  gps-profile:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  gps-profile
    ReadOnly:   false
  gps-theme:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  gps-theme
    ReadOnly:   false
  gps-sites:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  gps-sites
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-4t28k:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-4t28k
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age              From               Message
  ----     ------     ----             ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  4m               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/gps-restful-server to minikube
  Normal   Pulling    2m (x4 over 4m)  kubelet, minikube  pulling image "tux/gps:latest"
  Warning  Failed     2m (x4 over 4m)  kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "tux/gps:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for tux/gps, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
  Warning  Failed     2m (x4 over 4m)  kubelet, minikube  Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     2m (x6 over 4m)  kubelet, minikube  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff    2m (x7 over 4m)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off pulling image "tux/gps:latest"
```

How it's possible to pull the image from docker-hub in kubernetes?

Comment: Hi what is the correct value of  `Image: tux/gps:latest` ? It seems you are putting wrong value here.  
>>>>>as you can see here pull access denied for tux/gps, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Comment: I have fixed this issue. The correct server address is https://index.docker.io/v1/ instead of registry.hub.docker.com.

Comment: Hi, I answered the question down below, and provided a statement with a reference, it might be helpful to skim through .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Image tux/gps:latest does not exist because its a dummy value.
Solution to ImagePullBackoff:

1. Make sure that your Image points to latest version repouser/reponame:latest
2. Create a secret docker-registry (look above)
3. Server address[[docker-hub registry](https://index.docker.io/v1/)]
4. Add the following propertie in pod yaml file (look above):

imagePullSecrets:
  - name: secretkey

Comment: No. Using `repouser/reponame:latest` is no good. You want to use the exact tag of the image or hash there.

Answer (score 2):

`imagebackpulloff` might be caused because of the following reasons:

- The image or tag doesn’t exist
- You’ve made a typo in the image name or tag
- The image registry requires authentication
- You’ve exceeded a rate or download limit on the registry

Answer (score 2):

when you get an imagepullbackoff error in kubernetes, it is either the docker repository name is wrongly specified or the image tag is incorrect.

go back to your docker hub and confirm the tag version is correct.

if the image tag is V3 and you specified V1 in your kubernetes deployment manifest, it will cry foul.

also double check the repository name and what you have in your deployment manifest.

these little oversights can be a headache to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused due to the wrong value of key `pods.spec.containers.image`.

> The image property of a container supports the same syntax as the docker command does, including private registries and tags.

[k8s Images](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/)