# How do I publish .NET Core to Digital Ocean Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, digital-ocean

I am trying to publish a .NET Core Web App and a .NET Core API.

I have been googling and can't find a way to deploy 1 let alone 2 .NET Core apps to a Digital Ocean Kubernetes Cluster, I have 2 nodes and have created a valid manifest and build a Docker image locally and it seems to pass the validation. But I can't actually deploy it. I'm new to Kubernetes and anything I find seems to be related to Google's Kubernetes or Azure Kubernetes.

I don't, unfortunately, have more information than this.

Answer (score 0):

> I have one. Weird thing is that DO is actually smart to not have docs
>   since it doesn't have to. You can recycle Google's and Azure's K8
>   documentation to work on your DO cluster. The key difference is only
>   in the namings I suppose, there could be more differentiations but so
>   far, I haven't met a single problem while applying instructions from
>   GCP's docs.

https://nozomi.one is running on DO's k8 cluster.

Here's an awesome-dotnetcore-digitalocean-k8 for you.

**Errors you may/will face:**

- [Kubernetes - Error message ImagePullBackOff when deploy a pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54697970/kubernetes-error-message-imagepullbackoff-when-deploy-a-pod)
- Utilising .NET Core appsettings in docker k8

**Push the secret file here (Recommended only for staging or below, unless you have a super secret way to deploy this):**

```
kubectl create secret generic secret-appsettings --from-file=./appsettings.secrets.json
```

And then create a deployment configuration similar to this. Notice that we've added the appsettings at the last few lines:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: xxxxx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: xxxxx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: xxxxx
        image: xxxxx/xxxxxx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"
          value: "Production"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secrets
          mountPath: /app/secrets
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: secrets
        secret:
          secretName: secret-appsettings
```

Deploying this script is as simple as:

```
kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
```

And if you want to test locally in docker first:

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/test-app:v1
```

All in all, everything above will help you to deploy your pods.

You need to understand that deploying a new project/app works in this systematic way:

1. Create a deployment, which is something that pulls the image for you and creates pods that will be deployed to the nodes.
2. Create a service, that will point proper ports and more (Never tried to do more lol) to your app/s.

This is how a service looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nozweb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nozweb
```

Always ensure that spec:selector:app is specifically following:

```
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: xxxxx
```

In your deployment configuration. That's how they symlink.

3. Create an ingress **(Optional)** that will help act as a reverse proxy to your .NET Core app/project. ***This is optional because we got kestrel running!***